# Java Spring-integration TCP flush control

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration and the ServerSocketFactory is set to have decent receive and write buffers, as well as TCPNoDelay is set to false. This is verified set correctly on the socket with a debugger.

When writing to the outputstream in the spring-integration serializer, I see each write call being sent seperately with a TCP PSH (push) flag - i.e. a flush.

Why does this flush occur? How can I avoid this?

Comment: If you don't want excess flushing why are you disabling the Nagle algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to customize the serializer - they generally flush after all parts have been written (e.g. length header + payload; payload + CRLF; STX + payload + ETX; etc, etc).

Simply subclass the serializer of your choice and override the `serialize()` method to remove the `flush()`. Inject it into the connection factory.

EDIT:

Oh, I see - Nagle's algorithm only applies to subsequent writes (notice the payload and ETX are in a single packet). We need to wrap the stream in a buffered output stream. Please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

In the meantime, you can work around it with something like this...

```
/**
 * Writes the byte[] to the stream, prefixed by an ASCII STX character and
 * terminated with an ASCII ETX character.
 */
@Override
public void serialize(byte[] bytes, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
    bos.write(STX);
    bos.write(bytes);
    bos.write(ETX);
    bos.flush();
}
```

Comment: But I am trying to avoid a flush for each and every OutputStream.write() invocation, like for instance flushing after a single STX byte (causing TCP PSH flag). Flushing after the entire serialization is fine.

Comment: We only flush at the end... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/serializer/ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer.java#L87